# My puppy doesn't want to walk (Newfoundland/Bernese Mountain Dog)

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression, training

We have a puppy that is 3 months old (Newfoundland/Bernese Mountain Dog). He is very intelligent and he listens good but only when we are in side the house. When we are outside he gets dominant and doesn't want to walk and listen.

I know that I can't expect puppy's to listen inmediatly. But when he has enough (which is most of the time after 5 minutes) he sits in the grass and you can't get him to come along only if you're going back to the house. Last time he started growling at me.

I've never had this problem before, what can I do?

Comment: What about bringing treats to encourage him?

Comment: Are you sure that is dominant behaviour? It sounds to me like he may be worried/scared about moving too far away from him home.

Comment: Sometimes we take him and go for a drive so we can walk in some other forest. And when we walk doesn't matter where his tail is way up. And when we see a other dog, he goes is not afraid and goes straight towards him if we allow him(this can also be social skills he needs to develop) Now you can be right, that he's just afraid. How can I now this for sure? @Layna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving the dog where you put him. Then calling for him to come get treats. Also consider having a picnic in the grass so the dog see's that after a while nothing happened (that's if the dog is scared). Also don't force the dog to do it for 5 minutes every time, make it less, then every once in a while when you try to walk him try gradually increasing the time limit but don't get to five minutes until he's calm about the whole thing. If the dog moves from his spot give him a treat. If the dog want's to go home let it. Also make the dog stay on your porch for instance and YOU spend time being out there where he can see you.  Puppies need to feel safe and encouraged. And your puppy is obviously insecure and not sure of the out side world yet. The reason he walks in the forest is because he knows you're his safest place to be. But he doesn't really want to go for walks yet. And him going to other dogs and sniffing them means he's not afraid of dogs(unless you see fear signs) and that's good. He's maybe afraid of other stuff or just the idea of leaving home,where all consumables are. So show the dog treats,water and safety and all is going to be fine.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted it as an awnser because you explained it really good. And it makes sense I'm gonna try this out and if you don't hear from me again you know it worked ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it. I hope you never come back . Just kidding, any questions and i'm right at service. Hope you all the best, and for your dog.